# Uncovering Frames with Transparency and Invisibility at the same Time

Tags: beamer, overlays, transparency

Take the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
 
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\title[Title]{Title}
\author[Author]{Author}
\institute{Institute}
\date[21/10/1985]{21/10/1985}

\begin{document}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Transparency}

\begin{itemize}
\onslide<1>
\item Back

\onslide<2>
\item to

\onslide<3>
\item the

\onslide<4>
\item Future.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Presently, we have the following situation:

- in the first frame, the first bullet is visible and the remaining three are transparent;
- in the second frame, the second bullet is visible and the remaining three are transparent;
- in the third frame, the third bullet is visible and the remaining three are transparent;
- in the fourth frame, the fourth bullet is visible and the remaining three are transparent.

I have the following question. Can we obtain the following pattern?

- in the first frame, the first bullet is visible and the remaining three are invisible;
- in the second frame, the first bullet is transparent, the second bullet is visible, and the remaining two are invisible;
- in the third frame, the first and the second bullet are transparent, the third bullet is visible and the fourth is invisible;
- in the fourth frame, the first, the second bullet, and the third bullet are transparent, and the fourth is visible.

Thanks a lot in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the `still covered` opaqueness to 0% so that still covered items are not visible:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
 
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\setbeamercovered{%
  still covered={\opaqueness<1->{0}},
  again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Transparency}

\begin{itemize}[<+>]
\item Back
\item to
\item the
\item Future.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot: this works perfectly!

Comment: @Kolmin You're welcome!